# Show that if G is a group and $a,b \in G$ then $o(aba^{-1})= o(b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that if G is a group and $a,b \in G$ then $o(aba^{-1})= o(b)$

My attempt

Let $G$ be finite and let $b \in G$ then $o(b)=$ the least positive integer $n$ such that $b^n=e$. So,

$o(b)= b^n$

$o(aba^{-1})=(aba^-1)^n$

$(aba^{-1})^n= (ab)^na^{-1n}= (ba)^na^{-1n}= b^na^na^{-1n}=b^n(aa^{-1})^n=b^ne=b^n=o(b)$

Comment: $o(b)=b^n$ doesn't really make sense...

Comment: Your argument seems circular. Try computing $(aba^{-1})^n$ explicitly.

Comment: Your writing is sloppy. If $o(b) = \min\{n\in\Bbb N\,|\, b^n = e\}$, then $o(b) \neq b^n$. _Hint_: Consider cyclic groups generated by those elements.

Comment: In addition to the preceding remarks, note that the identity $(aba^{-1})^n=(ab)^n(a^{-1})^n$ assumes commutativity, in which case there is nothing to prove, hence it is widely off the mark. (Unrelated: *please* learn to type `^{-1}`.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $m=o(b)$ and $n= o(aba^{-1})$ both be finite, then observe
\begin{align}
(aba^{-1})^m = ab^m a^{-1} =e
\end{align}
which means $n\mid m$. Next, observe
\begin{align}
(aba^{-1})^n = ab^na^{-1} = e \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b^n=e
\end{align}
i.e. $m\mid n$. Hence $n=m$.

Comment: can you explain why $(aba^{-1})^m = ab^ma^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Try computing $(aba^{-1})^2$.

Comment: sorry i dont understand

Comment: im having a hard time understanding orders, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you need is a proof that
$$(aba^{-1})^n=ab^na^{-1}$$
You should be able to find one from this observation:
$$(ab^na^{-1})(aba^{-1})=ab^{n+1}a^{-1}$$
I trust you can verify this. This is the induction step in such a proof.